# linker doesn't find my static library. How to let linker find static library?

Tags: c

This is my project structure.

```
.
├── lib
│   └── simple_math.a
├── simple_math
│   ├── simple_math.c
│   ├── simple_math.h
│   └── simple_math.o
└── src
    └── main.c

4 directories, 5 files
```

I defined add function in simple_math.h located simple_math directory.

then I compile simple_math.c file to create object file.

I created library file simple_math.a from simple_math.o and It is under the lib directory.

After that, I compiled main.c file with linking flag.

But Something about linking is wrong.

This is my compile flags. I compiled my source code in src directory.

```bash
clang main.c -std=c89 -I ../simple_math -L ../lib -lsimple_math
```

It emits error like below.

```bash
ld: library not found for -lsimple_math
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It is my main.c file.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "simple_math.h"

int main(void)
{
  printf("Test: %d\n", add(10, 20));
  return 0;
}
```

simple_math.c

```c
#include "simple_math.h"

int add(int lhs, int rhs){
  return lhs + rhs;
}
```

How can I link my library file when I compile source code?

My development environment is

- M1 macOS.
- clang v14.0.3
- std89 in c

Comment: The filename for libraries is supposed to begin with 'lib', so you need to have `libsimple_math.a`

Comment: @pmg Thank you, I archived my static library again to libsimple_math.a. It works.
Does static library have to be name starting with lib? Is it Linux style?

Comment: @JayLee: The `-l` switch to the linker, used as `-lMyName`, means “look for a file named `libMyName.suffix`,” where “suffix” is one of the standard library suffixes. You do not have to use a name of this form with the linker; you can simply pass the linker the exact file name without `-l`, which could be `MyLibrary.MySuffix`. But if you use the `-l` switch, the file has to have a name of the preceding form.

Comment: @pmg: Re “The filename for libraries is supposed to begin”: To be precise, the file name for a library used with the `-l` switch is supposed to begin with `lib`. One does not have to use the `-l` switch. In general, any file name can be used for a library and can be passed to the linker explicitly, instead of with `-l`.